# Can I nest "WITH" clause in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Following query gives me an error:

> "ORA-32034: Unsupported use of WITH clause"

```
 WITH table_B as 
(
    SELECT * FROM (
        WITH table_A AS
            (SELECT 'Akshay' as NAME FROM DUAL)
        SELECT NAME FROM table_A
    ) WHERE NAME LIKE '%Aks%' ---<<< Note a filter here
)
SELECT * from table_B;
```

Is there a way out? Thanks

Comment: no,you can't nest them. you can use multiple cte's though.

Comment: There is a way out - you can "nest" them but not with that syntax. As Pham shows in her/his answer, you can define multiple subqueries in a single WITH clause, with later subqueries allowed to reference the earlier-defined ones - which is the point of "nesting". And, since Oracle 11.2, you can also have self-referencing subqueries in a WITH clause - the so-called "recursive query" or "recursive CTE" technique. A recursive CTE (in a WITH clause) also can reference other subqueries defined earlier in the same WITH clause.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should change your query to:

```
WITH table_a AS
(
    SELECT 'Akshay' as name 
    FROM dual
)
,table_b AS 
(
    SELECT name 
    FROM table_a
    WHERE name LIKE '%Aks%'
)
SELECT * 
FROM table_b;
```

Comment: Agree about this but I have a "filter" in inner SQL. Modifying SQL given in my question above. Please have a look.

Comment: @AkshayLokur You can just use any operators like normal query in a `CTE`: aggregate  /analytic functions, WHERE, GROUP BY,.....

Answer (score 1):

We can use like following:-

```
WITH 
table_A AS
            (SELECT 'Akshay' as NAME FROM DUAL),
table_B AS
            (SELECT * FROM table_A where NAME like 'Aks%') --<< Adding filter here now
SELECT * FROM table_B;
```

Cheers!